# Folland's Real Analysis Exercise 1.22a

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The exercise states:

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu^*$ the outer measure induced by $\mu$ according to (1.12), $\mathcal{M}^*$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$-measurable sets, and $\bar{\mu}=\mu^* | \mathcal{M}^*$.

a) If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\bar{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$. (Use Exercise 18.)

I don't understand what I need to prove in order to show the $\bar{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$. The book is not clear to me. Do I need to show that $\mathcal{M}^*$ contains all subsets of measure zero? And that if $E,F \subset \mathcal{M}$ where $\mu(F)=0$, then $\bar{\mu}(E \cup F) = \mu(E)$?

Is that what it means to be the completion of $\mu$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to show that:

1. $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathcal{M}^*$ and $\bar{\mu}|_{\mathcal{M}} = \mu$, 

2. $\bar{\mu}$ is complete (i.e. $\mu^*(E)=0 \Rightarrow E \in \mathcal{M}^*$)

Comment: Folland states that $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{M}^*$, but proving the rest of (1) makes sense. Also, I think proving (2) isn't quite enough. Let $S \in \mathcal{M}$ and $E \in A$, which is the $A$ defined in David's answer. Proving (2) shows $S \cup E \in \mathcal{M}^*$ (with a little extra work). Thus we know that $\bar{\mu}$ is complete. However, I think that we still would need to show that it is *the* completion as given by Folland in theorem 1.9.

Comment: In other words, that $\mathcal{M}^* \subset \{S \cup E, S \in \mathcal{M}, E \in A\}$. I'd like to hear your thoughts if you have the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. I was going to just point you to the definition in the book, but I see there is no formal definition of the completion of a measure space, instead he proves a theorem and says that that thing in the theorem is the completion.

Do you need to show that $\mathcal M^*$ "contains all subsets of measure zero"? That's not very precisely phrased - I can think of a few things it might mean.

Let $A$ be the set of all $E\subset X$ such that there exists $F\in\mathcal M$ with $E\subset F$ and $\mu(F)=0$. You need to show that $\mathcal M^*$ is equal to the set of all $S\cup E$ with $S\in\mathcal M$ and $E\in A$.

And you need to show that if $E\in M$ and $F\in A$ then $\overline\mu(E\cup F)=\mu(E)$.

Comment: Ya, there's not really a clear criteria for being the completion of a measure space. However, he does say that the completion he gives is unique, so that's something to go off of.

And your interpretation of "contains all subsets of measure zero" is what I was thinking.

It looks like we agree about what it means to be a completion of $\mu$, which basically boils down to showing that $\bar{\mu}$ is equivalent to the completion that Folland gives.

Thanks, I'll try to apply this and see what happens.